# Error message: Value of type '[MKMapView]?' has no member 'showsUserLocation'

Tags: xcode

I'm following a Mapkit tutorial to display the user location on a map but I get the error message "Value of type '[MKMapView]?' has no member 'showsUserLocation'" when using the code "mapView.showsUserLocation = true" is there any way of resolving this?

...
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

@IBOutlet var mapView: [MKMapView]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureLocationServices()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

private func configureLocationServices () {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if status == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: locationManager)        }
}
   private func beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
private func zoomToLatestLocation(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
     mapView.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
}
```

}
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did get latest location")

```
    guard let latestLocation = locations.first else { return }

    if currentCoordinate == nil {
        zoomToLatestLocation(with: latestLocation.coordinate)
    }
    currentCoordinate = latestLocation.coordinate  
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("The status changed")
    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        beginLocationUpdates(locationManager: manager)
    }
```

...

Anyway, thanks for any help you can offer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you’ve declared `mapView` as being an *array* of `MKMapView`s. That’s what the square brackets mean:

```swift
@IBOutlet var mapView: [MKMapView]!
```

The error message says that yes indeed, arrays do not have a `showsUserLocation` method.

If you need only one `mapView`, no need to make it an array:

```swift
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!